# Angular Drag and Drop onDrop callback method issue

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

Hey I am very new to Angular. To create a web game including the drag and drop feature, I used [this](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop). This is part of my code in html:

```
<div class="bucket"
     data-drop="true"
     data-jqyoui-options
     jqyoui-droppable="{onDrop:'onDrop'}"
     >
</div>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.alienData = [];

// Initialization of $scope.alienData
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $scope.alienData[i].push({alien:i, bucket:null});
};


//Add the bucket id to the corresponding alien
$scope.onDrop = function(event, ui) {
    var alienId = ui.draggable.attr('id');
    var bucketId = $(event.target).parent().attr('id');

    // Note that $scope.alienData is a list looks like this: 
    //[{alien:0, bucket:null}, {alien:1, bucket:null}, {alien:2, bucket:null}]
    $scope.alienData[alienId].bucket= bucketId;

    // HERE I got the correct bucketId printed
    alert($scope.alienData[alienId].bucket);
};

// This function is called by ng-click on the alien, click is happend after I dropped alien in the bucket
$scope.putBackAlien = function(alienId) {
    // HERE is where I check the list and got null value 
    alert($scope.alienData[alienId].bucket);
    // Some other work to put back alien
    ...
};
```

So basically everytime I dragged an alien item in a bucket, I want to modify $scope.alienData by adding the bucketId to the alien I dragged, so that I can use the data from this list later. However, I found that this worked well only inside the onDrop function (the alert with the correct bucketId will pop out everytime I dragged an alien in some bucket). If I checked $scope.alienData outside onDrop, I can't find the bucketId I just added in the onDrop function (which is null). 
Any suggestion on how can I fix this? Thanks!!!

Comment: what do you mean by `I can't find it outside the function`, how do you try to get it?

Comment: I use `alert($scope.alienData[alienId].bucket);` in another function to check the data, and there what I got is null. If I successfully mutate the list inside onDrop, it should give me the bucketId no matter where I call `alert()` on `$scope.alienData[alienId].bucket`.

Comment: is the other function invoked AFTER you dropped?

Comment: how do u call that function `ng-click` or what?

Comment: Yes, it's `ng-click`. And I clicked on the alien item after I dragged it in the bucket.

Comment: Also, I debugged in the browser and set two breakpoints at where I just dropped the alien and where I clicked on the alien. At the first breakpoint, the value in the list is the correct bucketId, then at the second breakpoint, the value is null again.

Comment: I would try to help you if you provide more code of your controller.

Comment: Thanks I just added more code.

Comment: is the `bucketId` a primitive value?

Comment: yep `bucketId` is just an id I assigned to each bucket, something looks like "bucket0"

Comment: I tried to do a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/mu2nNfZXlcXrMDP0R7nb?p=preview, but something is wrond there

Comment: Sorry for late update, I just tried another way: I created a new button somewhere and set a ng-click in its div. Then I call `alert($scope.alienData[alienId].bucket);`  in that button's ng-click callback and I got the correct bucketId! Does it imply the problem is actually from the alien's ng-click but not onDrop?

Comment: It might be related to the elements scope, (I don't know how you passed 'alienId' into the function).

Comment: I have that ng-click inside a ng-repeat where I get the alienId from list: 
`<div ng-repeat="a in m.alien"
         ng-dblclick=putBackAlien(m.model,a.alien)
         id="{{a.alien}}"
         data-drag="true"
         data-jqyoui-options="{'revert': 'invalid'}"
         jqyoui-draggable="{'animate': 'true'}">
         <img src={{a.img}} width="15%">
   </div>`